# How can I scrape links in all my webpages?

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I have this code so far that extracts text from the page URLs, using scrapy:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "dialpad"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'https://help.dialpad.com/hc/en-us/categories/201278063-User-Support',
        'https://www.domo.com/',
        'https://www.zenreach.com/',
        'https://www.trendkite.com/',
        'https://peloton.com/',
        'https://ting.com/',
        'https://www.cedar.com/',
        'https://tophat.com/',
        'https://www.bambora.com/en/ca/',
        'https://www.hoteltonight.com/'
    ]
    for url in urls:
        BASE_URL = url
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[2]
    filename = 'quotes-thing-{}.csv'.format(page)
    BASE_URL = response.url

    # with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    #     f.write(response.body)
    # # with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
      for selector in response.css('body').xpath('.//text()'):
        selector = selector.extract()
        f.write(selector)
```

How can I also extract data from the links on those pages and write them to that filename that I create?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CrawlSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) to extract each link and scrape them, your code could look like this

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider, Rule


class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dialpad"

    start_urls = [
        'https://help.dialpad.com/hc/en-us/categories/201278063-User-Support',
        'https://www.domo.com/',
        'https://www.zenreach.com/',
        'https://www.trendkite.com/',
        'https://peloton.com/',
        'https://ting.com/',
        'https://www.cedar.com/',
        'https://tophat.com/',
        'https://www.bambora.com/en/ca/',
        'https://www.hoteltonight.com/'
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(r'url patterns here to follow'),
                deny=(r'other url patterns to deny'),
            ),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True,
        )
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[2]
        filename = 'quotes-thing-{}.csv'.format(page)

        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            for selector in response.css('body').xpath('.//text()'):
                selector = selector.extract()
                f.write(selector)
```

Though I recommend creating a different spider for each website, and use `allow` and `deny` parameters to choose which links you want to be extracted on each website.

also it would be much better to use [Scrapy Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)